# How to remove lines that not containing any uppercase letters or lowercase letters or numbers notepad++

Tags: notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, text-editing

I want to keep only lines that contain

at least 1 uppercase letter

at least 1 lowercase letter

at least 1 number

Example:

```
:soTest.@1rTr
:$TEST%.TER12TB&
:-G5O6D$G%R@RS
:sbg^45re$55
:@65RR$#955
:*S.baR5t6s
```

Result:

```
:soTest.@1rTr
:*S.baR5t6s
```

so the idea that if the whole line in any position after : not contain any of both uppercase letters and lowercase letters and a number remove it or bookmark it or vice versa

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use regexp for this.
I am not used to notepad++, but ctrl+H should open replace. (I've tried the following on sublime text 3)

```
^(?!(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+$)).*$
```

This should match all those that are not part of the result.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+$
```

This should match lines that are part of the result.
So match lines not part of the result and replace them with the empty string

Answer (score 0):

The following regex in the Find&Replace should be able to do what you are looking for:

```
^(?:((?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).+)|.+[\r\n]*)
```

Ensure that you have Match case checked and Regular expression Search Mode, the replace is `$1`, and the you have either selected the whole text or the cursor is at the beginning of the text (regular expression replace occurs in only one direction before or after the cursor's current position):

[image]

[image]

The expression matches both the strings you want to keep and those you want to delete, but places back only those you want to keep after matching.