# How to remove lines that don't contain at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and special symbol in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, text-editors, find-and-replace

After looking across the internet for about an hour, I decided to register an account and ask a question :)

I'd like to remove all lines that don't contain at least one uppercase letter, lowercase letter, number and special symbol [Examples of Special Symbols: !@#$%^&*()] in Notepad++

Example Input:

```
josukeisbig
JOSUKEISBIG
JosukeIsBig
JosukeIsB1g
JosukeIsB1g!
```

Example Output:

```
JosukeIsB1g!
```

The only related thread I found was this:
[How to remove lines that not containing any uppercase letters or lowercase letters or numbers notepad++](https://superuser.com/questions/1412772/how-to-remove-lines-that-not-containing-any-uppercase-letters-or-lowercase-lette)

But OP didn't specify special characters.

- Thanks!

Comment: I believe this will answer your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559751/regex-to-make-sure-that-the-string-contains-at-least-one-lower-case-char-upper

Comment: Zero Length match error? @Sergiu Elmi

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: In Notepad ++, it also returns lines without special characters through results. And replaces the results with ^ zero length match on a white background until you move onto the next one.

Comment: @Sergiu Elmi ???

Comment: I can't test it in Notepad++ because I'm on Linux, but I think that's because "=?" doesn't capture what is in the parentheses. You should see what each expression means before using it. I'll post an answer shortly with a working regex exp. Check this for instance - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1570896/what-does-mean-in-a-regular-expression

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below regexp:

```
^(?!(^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\]]).+$)).*$
```

In Notepad++ you can either search for this regexp, replace all with an empty string and then go to:

> Edit >> Line Operations >> Remove Empty Lines

As an alternative to delete them, instead of using Find & Replace, you can use the Mark tab from the same window and mark all lines using the same regexp. To delete them, go to:

> Search >> Bookmark >> Remove Bookmarked Lines

---

A screenshot for convenience:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Select "Mark" tab
- Find what: `^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\w\r\n]).+$`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- **CHECK** *Bookmark line*
- <kbd>Mark all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   #  beginning of line
  (?=.*[a-z])       # lookahead, make sure we have a lowercase
  (?=.*[A-Z])       # lookahead, make sure we have an uppercase
  (?=.*\d)          # lookahead, make sure we have a digit
  (?=.*[^\w\r\n])   # lookahead, make sure we have a non-word, non-linebreak
  .+                # 1 or more any character
$                   # end of line
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Second step:

```
Menu => Search => Bookmark => Remove Unmarked Lines.
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]